# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Tags: c#

I try to calculate VAT RATE but when I try to debug,my code gives me error;

```
Double toplamd = Convert.ToDouble(TOPLAM.Text);
Double kdvtutard = Convert.ToDouble(kdvtutar.Text);
kdvsiztutar.Text = "0.0";
Double kdvsiztutard = Convert.ToDouble(kdvsiztutar.Text);
kdvsiztutard = toplamd - kdvtutard;
kdvsiztutar.Text = kdvsiztutard.ToString();
decimal result = (100 * Convert.ToDouble(kdvtutard)) / kdvsiztutar; 
kdvoran.Text = "%" + result;
```

Comment: It is not an error when you debug, the compiler won't let you get away with this mistake and yells first.  You already know how to convert a number in a TextBox to a double, note how you used Convert.ToDouble() before.  You just forgot to do it as well for the kdvsiztutar control.  Do keep in mind that you should not use Convert.ToDouble(), it is going to be awfully unhappy when you type the wrong text, or none at all, and will crash your program.  Decimal.TryParse() is the better way.

Answer (score 7):

The error does say what's wrong, really. :)

You're trying to divide a number with a text box, which is wrong.

You probably meant `kdvsiztutard`, which is the value of `kdvsiztutar` you've already converted to a double and massaged.

(By the way, this is a good example of why you'll want to name things well.)

Comment: oow my biggest mistake thank you so much